# Slow Startup of Desktop Application

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008, desktop-application

What are possible reasons for **slowness at startup** of an application developed in **.NET 3.5** ?
Which factor can be involved in this issue and how this sort of issue avoided ?

Comment: Your code is slow? The PC is slow? The stars are not aligned? Without any code or background information, this is just guessing.

Comment: Usually the reason is the code that runs at startup.

Comment: Use a .net performance  profiler to find out

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head....

Slow/Intense start up code. This will probably be in Program, a constructor of an object created at startup or the Show/Load events of the first form.

A Database/Internet based connection at start up, **especially** if that connection is unable to connect. It never fails to surprise how many people write synchronous network related code and complain of their app being slow.

A large number of libraries being loaded, this is an odd one since the performance profiler don't always show what you are waiting for.

Note that ALL of the above can be run within a start up/splash screen with a progress bar.